What is the difference between digital and analog quantum computing?
I have difficulties to catch the difference between digital (gate-based) and analog quantum computers (excluding quantum annealers).
The true difference I understand is that time evolution is discrete for digital computers (gate by gate), but continuous for analog computers (no gates so far).
As an example, IBM QPUs are gate based, there is no way to my knowledge to implement a continuous evolution except by discretizing it (e.g. Trotterization). Conversely, Pasqal QPUs currently offer only (at the moment) an analog approach (though they may have a digital circuit to analog evolution converter), which they claim to be more suited to the NISQ era as qubits in this approach are less prone to decoherence.
But then, given an unitary evolution $U$, you may either discretize it and build a circuit approximation for it, or translate it in a physical continuous evolution of qubits.
So, from the point of view of someone just wanting to solve a problem, there is no real difference, except that one approach may better run than another for a given problem.
Am I right ? If so, are there some problems running better on digital QPUs than on analog ones ? or conversely some problems running better on analog QPUs ? Also, are these differences
rather due to current limitations of quantum computing (qubit decoherence, limited circuit depth or time duration evolution) or will they still hold to some extent at FTQC era ?

Perhaps, should I have talked about "continuous variable" quantum computing instead of "analog" quantum computing. The former is also being developed.

in fairness, continuous variable (CV) quantum computing (QC) is related to "analog quantum computing", in the sense that it's a natural approach to understand what "analog QC" means. At the same time, there might be other ways to understand what "analog quantum computing" means, afaik, so if you're asking about CV QC you're better off clarifying that from the get go. All this said, asking "the difference between CV and DV QC" is an extremely broad question. Did you have a look at standard reviews on the topic, eg the dedicated chapter of https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0410100?

for example, it matters if you're looking at continuous variables to find ways to digitize them. In which case the problem is just how to implement a "standard" qubit-based quantum computer from a physical substratum that operates on continuous variables. On the other hand, you might be looking for ways to directly work with continuous variables without digitisation (eg what quantum annealers attempt to do), and that's a very different thing
